# Embed Adobe Reader in custom Android (or PhoneGap) Application

Tags: android, cordova, pdf, mobile, sdk

We have a need to embed PDF reader in one of our custom built Android (or PhoneGap Plugins) tablet application from local directory (Sdcard). Embed meaning is not just display pdf document inside the application instead we have to tap the following API functionalities programmatically:

1)  Retrieve pdf document meta data i.e. Page Size, Author, Date Created
2)  Tap next and previous page click and implement our custom handler code
3)  Zoom, Pinch, page swipe etc.

**1) Can someone help us or give direction to achieve the above use cases using Adobe Acrobat reader (Adobe Reader Mobile 9 SDK)?**

**2) Whether Adobe Reader Mobile 9 SDK exposes API to program against? The FAQ section doesn’t talk about the API for the above mentioned use case**

We have spent time  in googling & StackOverflow  mining to find the possibilities but no luck. What was our conclusion after the analysis is we have to go for open source or commercial embeddable pdf sdk’s i.e.

•   Mozilla’s Pdf.JS
•   Android Pdf Viewer Library
•   Foxit pdf viewer library
•   Radaee.pdf, Embeddable Mobile PDF SDK
•   The Adobe Reader Mobile SDK

**We have tried the above mentioned libraries and below are our experience**

**Mozilla’s Pdf.JS** – It is a JavaScript solution and exposes API for all of our need but fails to render the PDF for some cases whenever some special embedded font is missing and in such cases the application crashes. Other than this single issue it very promising and superb. Still it is in beta stage.

**Android Pdf Viewer Library** – We have built a Custom Intent (PhoneGap Android Plugins) but it is very slow and fails in many cases. We felt PDF.JS is much better than Android Pdf Viewer Library

**Radaee.pdf** – Currently exploring. The Knowledge base is very poor and not enough samples to move forward

**Foxit pdf viewer library** – Unable to download the SDK from the URL they sent in the email after registering with Foxit.  Though the link says PDF SDK but it downloads only the pdf reader. We sent an email to their sales team and awaiting their response.

**The Adobe Reader Mobile SDK** – SDK is not available to download, one need to get it through their re-sellers. We sent a request to them and awaiting for their callback

o   Datalogics
o   Bsquare
o   Bluefire

Appreciate your response & support

Comment: Add Qoppa and PdfTron to the list.  Both expensive, but the best I've seen so far.  They can do everything you want, although it may require some effort by you still.

Answer (score 0):

Please try ProCore Mobile SDK (http://www.mobilepdfsdk.com). They say that you can embed PDF reader in 5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [RadaeePDF-Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/gearit/RadaeePDF-Cordova) and do the following to add it:

1. Create the app using the demo package name, to be able to test all
   the features (standard, professional and premium).

   ```
   cordova create RadaeePDF-Cordova com.radaee.reader RadaeePDF-Cordova
   ```
2. Add the android/iOS platform.

   ```
   cd RadaeePDF-Cordova 
   cordova platform add android --save and/or cordova platform add ios --save
   ```
3. Add the plugin.

   ```
   cordova plugin add https://github.com/gearit/RadaeePDF-Cordova.git --save
   ```
4. Build the app. `cordova build`